# NETGEAR FS750T, all lights on but doesn't appear to be working

Tags: networking, switch

I picked up a secondhand [NETGEAR FS750T](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/FS750T) switch today for very little as the previous owner said it had stopped working.

After powering it up, there is a small noise for about three seconds. All the lights above the 10/100 ports are solid green and I can't access the web interface when connecting it up to my computer.

What could the problem be? I've heard others with different switch models reporting that all the lights are flashing and replacing the capacitors fixes them. Could this be the same problem? I'd really like to get this switch working!

I've tried the reset and factory reset buttons. The reset just puts all the lights off for the duration of holding it and the factory reset appears to do nothing.

**Edit**: when I turn it on, all the lights and the sound starts immediately. After two seconds, the lights go out. After three seconds, the sound stops and the lights return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening the switch's case, I saw four 1000uF 16V capacitors that seemed to have bulging tops, so I assumed they were broke.

I ordered the exact same ones to replace the broken ones with and the switch now works again.